# PHP change div display according to form content

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to filter a page of divs to display or not depending on the form input.  This would be something similar to a page of articles in that each div displays a picture and some text which links to the full article. This is at the top of the page:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
                    Team:
                    <select value="team">
                        <option>Any</option>
                        <option>A</option>
                        <option>B</option>
                    </select>
                    Map: 
                    <select value="map">
                        <option>Any</option>
                        <option>A</option>
                        <option>B</option>
                    </select>
                    Site:
                    <select value="site">
                        <option>Any</option>
                        <option>A</option>
                        <option>B</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Filter Content">
</form>
```

In the main section of the page, each div looks like this with the same 'item' class.

```
<div class="item">
                <?php
                    $info = array("A", "B", "A");
                    $display = "block";
                ?>
                <div style="display:<?$display?>">
                <p>text text text</p>
                </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind there are multiple divs in a row with the same class.  I gave each div a $info array which is used to compare the form input.  However, I cannot figure out how to compare the two. I was just simply going to change the $display variable to "none" or "block" depending upon if the $info variable and form input matched.

This is where I am having the most trouble... I do not understand how to parse each div in the page.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
                {
                $filter = array($_POST['team'], $_POST['map'], $_POST['site']);
                $html = file_get_contents('example.php');
                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                $dom->loadHTML($html);
                $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
                $divContent = $xpath->query('//div[id="item"]');
                foreach ($divContent as $div)
                {
                    if ($filter != $div->$info)
                    {
                        $div->$display = "none";
                    }
                }
                }
```

I realize there are a few errors with the code, but since I am in the midst of learning PHP I do not know what to change.  So, how do I filter the divs to display/not display by comparing the arrays assigned to each div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I don't think you really need PHP to do this unless you are pulling this content from a server. If that is the case, it sounds like something you are doing with categories. Thinking about it like that, again, PHP really doesn't make them show or hide, JS or CSS can do that.

PHP will bring in the information from the server and nothing more. For example, if on your database you have a column called 'category' you can do something like this with your HTML.

```
<div id="<?php ** ?>"> CONTENT </div>
```

The ** will be the information to pull what category that information is in. From there, your JS can show/hide - CSS can do it too.